# How can I detect and recognize the digits in a answer key like the given image?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, deep-learning

I have this image and I have to detect and store the answers and the corresponding question number. I tried using OCR but it wasn't recognising anything properly. Is there any other way?

```
import cv2
from imutils import contours
import numpy as np
import pytesseract

config = '-l eng+equ --oem 3 --psm 8'

# Load image, grayscale, and adaptive threshold
image = cv2.imread('answerkey.png')
original = image.copy()
original1= image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
cv2.imshow("thresh",thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# Filter out all numbers and noise to isolate only boxes
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

(cnts,_) = contours.sort_contours(cnts, method="top-to-bottom")
(cnts,_) = contours.sort_contours(cnts, method="left-to-right")
print(cnts)
completetext=[]
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if 500 < area <5000:
        # cv2.imshow("cnt", original)
        # cv2.waitKey(0)
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        crop = original1[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        gray1 = cv2.cvtColor(crop, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        # cv2.imshow("cropp",crop)
        # cv2.waitKey(0)
        kernel = np.zeros((2,2), np.uint8)
        erode = cv2.erode(gray1, kernel,iterations=2)

        cv2.imshow("cropp erode", erode)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(erode, config=config)
        print(text)
```

[The Input Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqPqq.png)

I am getting blunder texts using the ocr directly on the complete image. Then I tried cropping each block and then feeding into OCR still I am not getting good results.
If someone knows better way please help me with this

Comment: If you get rid of the lines, scale it by 3x, and run it with PSM 6, you'll get very good recognition. To get rid of lines you might be able to find them with [Hough lines](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d6/d10/tutorial_py_houghlines.html) and overwrite those sections with white pixels. To make sure you don't overwrite letters, throw away short lines.

Comment: amazing man, it really worked smooth. Actually I wasn't resizing the image and I think that was the issue. But could you give an explanation to how rescaling the image to 3x made the recognition so good?

Comment: Tesseract likes characters to be a [minimum height](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdoc/blob/master/FAQ-Old.md#is-there-a-minimum--maximum-text-size-it-wont-read-screen-text) in pixels. You have a high quality image, but the heights of the letters were approx 11 pixels.

Comment: oh yeah I should have gone thoroughly through the tess-doc. Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

try to:

1. remove all the lines.
2. connect the components(numbers) vertically.
3. find contours(columns of text) and sort them from left to right.
4. slice the image according to the column contours.
5. pass individual slices to tesseract with appropriate psm value whitelisting digits.

hope this solves your problem.